# Return system console output to user interface

Tags: r, shiny

I have a bash script that i'm running using shiny and `system`. It takes a long time to run so I'd like to provide feedback to the user about progress. In the bash script I have messages that periodically updates the user and I'm trying to find a way to have them printed in the UI.

Here is a minimal working example for which I'd like to have "Output 1" and "Output 2" returned to the user as they appear in the console.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run", "Print to Console")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$run,{
    system(c("echo output 1; sleep 2; echo output 2"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to run your `system` command asynchronously and redirect the output to a log file. In parallel you can continuously read in the logfile via `reactiveFileReader`.

In contrast, when `intern = TRUE` the R session (and shiny) is blocked while the command is executed.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)

file.create("commands.sh", "output.log")
Sys.chmod("commands.sh", mode = "0777", use_umask = TRUE)
writeLines(c("#!/bin/bash", "echo output 1","sleep 2", "echo output 2"), con = "commands.sh")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run_intern", "Run intern"),
  textOutput("myInternTextOutput"),
  hr(),
  actionButton("run_extern", "Run extern"),
  textOutput("myExternTextOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  systemOutputIntern <- eventReactive(input$run_intern,{
    system(command = "echo output 1; sleep 2; echo output 2", intern = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$myInternTextOutput <- renderText(systemOutputIntern())
  
  observeEvent(input$run_extern,{
    system(command = "./commands.sh 2>&1 | tee output.log", intern = FALSE, wait = FALSE)
  })
  
  log <- reactiveFileReader(200, session, filePath = "output.log", readLines)
  output$myExternTextOutput <- renderText(log())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

PS: As an alternative you might want to check `AsyncProgress` from library([ipc](https://github.com/fellstat/ipc)).

Comment: There’s no need to go the detour via a file if you’re executing the external command asynchronously, i.e. via `pipe`.

Comment: Then, how would you get the output into a shiny reactive?

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for the suggestions. The only problem that I have right now is that the outputs appear in the UI all at once, not in succession, so that the user is still wondering what the progress is. like if we set `sleep 100` we'd that wouldn't be very useful. Any ideas?

Comment: @StephenWilliams I just tested on Ubuntu and you are right. It's not working as expected when running the commands directly using `system` (I don't know why). However it does work after wrapping the commands in a separate script. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ismirsehregal this worked really well. thanks!

Comment: @ismirsehregal I have tried running this using other commands on our cluster. Like Module load to load certain programs. However, that did not work. I get an `error ../commands.sh: line 1: module: command not found`
Does Rshiny load an source shell or it creates a new env for shell all together ?